# Mysqli é seguro contra SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, recentemente tive a ler um artigo de segurança contra SQL Injection, e vi que os mesmos no artigo recomendavam a conexão e a interacção do banco de dados por PDO e não por mysqli.

Gostaria de saber, se realmente mysqli é seguro contra SQL Injection, e se não quais são as soluções para contornar a situação.

Obrigado

Comment: Vinculada: [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/18246)

Comment: QUalquer tecnologia é seguro ou insegura conforme o programador usa, nada é seguro se o programador não entende profundamente tudo o que está acontecendo no código dele. @jbueno Vai essa mesmo :)